# Lifespan of open handles in a python generator body

Tags: python, generator

I have a question about generators and/or python's execution model.

Given something like:

```
def g(filename):
    with open(filename) as handle:
        for line in handle:
            yield some_trasformation_on(line)
```

My main confusion is: What happens to handle if

```
res = g()
print(next(res))
```

is called only once? Does the handle stay open for the life of the program? What if we have scarce resources being allocated in a generator body? Threads? Database handles?

Perhaps I am considering generators to be like functions under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer with the code as written

As described, **the file will stay open for the life of the program.**  While you have a reference to the *res* variable, it keeps the generator stackframe is alive, so the only way to get the with-statement to close the file is to keep calling [*next()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) until the for-loop ends normally.

### How to clean-up the generator

The tool designed for generator clean-up is [*generator.close()*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#new-generator-method-close) which raises a [*GeneratorExit*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.GeneratorExit) inside the generator.

Here is some working code to show how it could be done:

```
def genfunc(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as datafile:
            for line in datafile:
                yield len(line)
    finally:
        print('Status: %s' % datafile.closed)
```

And here is a sample session showing the closing operation actually takes place:

```
>>> g = genfunc('somefile.txt')
>>> next(g)
23
>>> g.close()
Status: True
```

Comment: It would have been great to have an example with 'with' statement since I think using 'with' is often encouraged for auto closing of handles.